# Count the number of times a set of characters appear in a file without BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to count the number of times a string appears in a file.  I want to find the number of times that "A, E, I, O, U" appears exactly in that order.  Here is the text file:

```
AEIOU aeiou baeiboeu bbbaaaaaa beaeiou caeuoi ajejijoju aeioo
aeiOu ma me mi mo mu
take it OUT!
```

I want the method to then return how many times it is in the file. Any idea's on how I could go about doing this?  The catch is I want to do this without using `BufferedReader`.  I can simply just read the file using `Scanner`.  Is there a way to do this?

I edited this and added the code I have so far.  I don't think I am even close.  I am pretty sure I need to use some nested loops to make this happen.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AEIOUCounter 
{  
  public static final String DELIM = "\t";

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    File filename = new File("aeiou.txt");

    try
    {
      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

      while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
      {
        System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e); 
    }
    fileScanner.close();
  } 
}
```

Comment: You put a `BufferedReader` on top of a `InputStream`. Do not put it over and use the `InputStream` and decode every byte into a String.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected result? Also, pasting the file content in your question, instead of the screenshot, will help others use the same content for testing purposes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have already written.

Comment: Yeah, _dont want to use InputStream_ proceeds to use Scanner. The Scanner literally uses a InputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing now, is printing all the lines in the file.

```
fileScanner.hasNextLine()
fileScanner.nextLine()
```

But what you are looking for is filtering out separate words in the file:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(path);

int counter = 0;
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String word = sc.next();
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("AEIOU")) {
        counter += 1;
    }
}
System.out.print("Number of words: " + counter);
```

Comment: Yeah, he wants to achieve this without using a InputStream. This is not going to happen with the Scanner either. The Scanner uses a InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Smurf's answer is great. It's worth mentioning that if you're using Java 8, you can avoid using a `Scanner` at all, and do this in a single expression:

```
long count =  Files.lines(Paths.get("aeiou.txt"))
                   .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                   .filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("aeiou"))
                   .count();
```

Comment: I don't want to be the Grinch, but `Files.lines` is using a BufferedReader :)